# How to use "return-path" in php mail function

Tags: php, email, function

What is that return path for?

Can i Use in this way?

```
mail($to_address, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f".$return_path );
```

Where:

```
$return_path = "C:/www/project/handlebounceemail.php";
```

Additional:

How to direct the email to a php script? I want to read the email and check for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$return_path` refers to the email address to which undeliverable messages will be sent. This does not refer to a file or URL. So you could use:

```
$return_path = "bounces@example.com";
```

The next step would be for you to write a script to read the mailbox of the `bounces` user and do something based on the contents. The exact operations required to do that are dependent on your email system.

Comment: How should I refer to a file then? I need to direct it to a php file.

Comment: How to write a script that read particular bounced emails? Can give me a short example?